# Shuffle numpy array without split

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 4D `numpy` array for input to a `CNN` similar to this generated data:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(20, 1, 10, 4)
```

And the corresponding label (in a separate array) `y` is

```
y = [0,0,0,....0]
```

So that the first instance of my input looks like:

```
>>>X[0]
array([[[0.11529038, 0.56951377, 0.64859216, 0.53927201],
        [0.24599472, 0.99658675, 0.61760602, 0.23245005],
        [0.21688713, 0.87376011, 0.80853348, 0.95649564],
        [0.01096112, 0.36735236, 0.23917356, 0.06020551],
        [0.14795334, 0.31689876, 0.902638  , 0.95702681],
        [0.59684508, 0.53496984, 0.91312413, 0.17465782],
        [0.37409845, 0.51140496, 0.32453245, 0.59066936],
        [0.64259922, 0.6586773 , 0.13101008, 0.71666185],
        [0.59971516, 0.96920186, 0.8566649 , 0.37763693],
        [0.34957495, 0.88521399, 0.30383687, 0.23567811]]])

>>>len(y)
20
```

I would like to shuffle my data set before feeding into the network but I cannot use sklearn `train_test_split` which split the data into the train-test. My dataset is already separated into train test but would like to shuffle before the model fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
train_idx = np.random.permutation(train_set.shape[0])
train_x, train_y = train_x[train_idx], train_y[train_idx]
```

Similarly for val and test.

Comment: Thank you, so I can pass `train_x, train_y = np.random.shuffle(train_x,train_y)` since the labels are in separate array? To make sure labels corresponds to its features?

Answer (score 0):

sklearn has a [`shuffle`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) method

```py
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X, y = shuffle(X, y)
```